# Return sound with equal probability each time

Tags: java, random

I have created a class in Java named Chick. Which contains three variables, name and two sounds. I have a method named getSound() which will return either sound with equal probability each time. How will I do that??

My sample code is here :

```
class Chick implements Animal {  
    private String myType;    
    private String mySound;    
    private String mySound2;

    public Chick(String type, String sound,String sound2)
    {
        myType = type;  
        mySound = sound;
        mySound2=sound2;
    } 

    public String getSound() 
    {
        return mySound;
    }     
}
```

Which change I have to make in the getSound method?? Please help me with detailed answer. If you can please write down the method with proper requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The smallest change to your code to make this work would be:

```
public String getSound() {
    return Math.random() < .5 ? mySound : mySound2;
}
```

If you had many sounds, I'd use an array:

```
private String[] sounds = new String[10]; // eg 10 sounds

public String getSound() {
    return sounds[new Random().nextInt(sounds.length)];
}
```

Note that mathematically 2 may be considered "many": The array version could be used for 2 sounds.

---

For a flexible solution, also use a varargs parameter in the constructor allowing any number of sounds:

```
punic class Animal {
    private final String[] sounds; 

    public Animal(String type, String... sounds) {
        this.sounds = sounds;
    }

    public String getSound() {
        return sounds[new Random().nextInt(sounds.length)];
    }
}
```

Comment: How the above random methods works? Will you please explain? @Bohemian

Comment: @user3435851 it generates an integer with the range of the array's size, which is used as an index pointer for the return. So it's essentially returning `sounds[0-2]` (0 through 2)

Comment: [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) returns a (pseudo) random greater than or equal to `0.0` and less than `1.0`. [`Random.nextInt(n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()) returns an integer greater than or equal to `0` and less than `n`.